# IIS Website IP Change

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

So my IIS7 server was hosting an ASP.Net web site with **domain xxx-xxx.com** with **IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy**.

Few days ago, I changed my ISP, which in result, changed my IP address to **zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz**.

Obviously the web site is down at the moment.

```
ping xxx-xxx.com
```

Results into:

```
Pinging xxx-xxx.com [yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Reply from yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy: Destination host unreachable.
Ping statistics for yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss)
```

As seen above, domain name xxx-xxx.com is still assigned to my old IP address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy xxx-xxx.com.

According to my friend, and excuse me my ignorance and lacking experience, there's a really simple step I must take in IIS7 in order to get the web site back online, however, I'm not entirely sure how. I tried editing bindings and setting IP address, however that does not work, neither did netsh iplisten add work.

Furthermore, correct me if I'm wrong, but do I need to go to the place domain name was bought from and change assigned IP address?

Comment: You need to find out where your domain DNS is registered.  This is most likely the place where you registered the domain name at.  Go into the dns settings and change the A record to your new ip.

Comment: Thank you that was exactly what was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the command

```
netsh http add iplisten ipaddress=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

It is necessary to restart IIS7 for the change to take affect.

Comment: Thank you. I also went to the site the domain was bought from and changed the IP Address of the domain. Not sure if this was needed or not, but it still had the old address assigned to the domain. 

There was also an option called "Domain Name Pointing Options" which I didn't change.